# CLR20r3 Exception

Tags: c#

I wrote a small C# app. Installed it in the admin account. It worked fine.

When I tried to execute it from a non-Admin account and another Admin account, it threw an error.

```
CLR20r3 System.Security.Security Exception
```

and the application stopped working.

What can be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a security issue.  What piece of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: I could not find that. However, I changed the security to Full Rights and even tried running it as Administrator. I got the same error. It only runs in the user account where I installed. On any other Admin as well as Non-Admin account, it doesn't work and throws this error

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  Unfortunately without it, we're all guessing blindly.

Comment: Hi, this is  the trace I am getting
"System.Security.SecurityException. Requested Registry access is not allowed. "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Improve your app's unhandled exception handling.  Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Or use a debugger.